# Why/how can Javascript classes access their own values with an underscore prefixed before them?

Tags: javascript

I found found a class in a tutorial that allows the getter and setter functions to access a field called visible set in the constructor that has the same name as the getter/setter by prefixing an underscore. What is going on here? Why does this work, shouldn't the getter/setter functions fail to the find the field name since it is incorrect?

```
class WeirdClass {
        constructor() {
            this.visible = false;
        }
        get visible() {
            return this._visible;
        }
        set visible(v) {
            this._visible = v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.visible = false;` calls the setter for `visible`, which creates `_visible`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense

Comment: Try `let foo = new WeirdClass(); console.log(foo._visible);`. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine if this was the case without the `_visible` where we directly access the `this.visible` from the getter and setter:

```
class WeirdClass {
     constructor() {
         this.visible = false;
     }
     get visible() {
         return this.visible; //calls the getter recursively
     }
     set visible(v) {
         this.visible = v; //calls the setter recursively
     }
}
```

Here there is no `_visible` we are accessing the `this.visible` in all cases. In this case when you access the `visible` property on the instance of the `WeirdClass`, it will trigger the getter which will try to access the `this.visible` property which will again call the getter and it will result in an infinite recursion.

To prevent this from happening they created a `_visible` property on the instance, so that when you access the `visible` property from the `WeirdClass` instance it won't cause infinite recursion and actually access another property `_visible` through the getter/setter.

In fact, if you try to instantiate the `WeirdClass` it won't even let you:

```js
class WeirdClass {
     constructor() {
        this.visible = false;
     }
     get visible() {
        return this.visible; //calls the getter recursively
     }
     set visible(v) {
        this.visible = v; //calls the setter recursively
     }
}
//Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
const weirdClass = new WeirdClass();
```

This is because the constructor is trying to set `false` in the `this.visible` which triggers the setter recursively.

Comment: IMHO, this is insane. I mean, I get it would have added complexity to the parser, but couldn't they design it so that if it was inside a getter/setter it would know to access the variable directly?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: It would have added complexity to the *language*, not the parser. What exists is a much simpler (and imo that means better) design.

Answer (score 0):

> has the same name as the getter/setter by prefixing an underscore

That's a very common theme in JS. Privacy by convention.

By prefixing the property with one or multiple underscores you signal that this is some private or internal property and not part of the public API for this class, and therefore consumers of these objects should stay away from these properties.

> shouldn't the getter/setter functions fail to the find the field name since it is incorrect

It's not exactly incorrect. It just doesn't exist, yet. In JS it is no error to access a property that is not defined (yet). It simply evaluates to `undefined`. And JS Objects are by default mutable. So you can add new properties at any time.